# What means when method is italic in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-14

By default, IntelliJ IDEA shows some of the methods as italic when we call them:

Example:

```
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
```

*`getContext()`* is italic, but `getAuthentication()` isn't, what does it mean?

Comment: I guess italic format is related to static methods.

Comment: In eclipse (i don't about other IDE's) italic means it is a static method which is called

Comment: In JavaScript exported functions are italic (including arrow functions) and other exports are purple.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A method written in italic indicate that this method is a static method.