# What is the meaning of a yellow and italic method name in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

What is the meaning of a yellow and italic method name in Android Studio, such as in this screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yellow and italic is an indication for extension function in Kotlin

Comment: Is `String.isBlank()` an extension function?

Comment: This extension is actually defined for `CharSequence`. So, yes, it's an extension function `CharSequence.isBlank()`

Comment: (1) So my answer is wrong? (2) Why is this defined as an extension function rather than a method?

Comment: You're right, I tried `String.subSequence` which is directly implemented as member method, and it didn't highlight!

Comment: Could you cite a source in your answer?

Comment: @xjcl This is a part of the color theme `Darcula` and it's configurable. You can find it in the IDE settings: `Editor -> Color Scheme -> Kotlin -> Functions -> Extension function call`

Comment: Ah, I see! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Kind of guessing here since I can't find the answer online.

**Italic: Functions defined in Kotlin**, such as `unescapeHtml` (which I defined elsewhere in this Kotlin app) and `thread`. Not to be confused with [Java static methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33894914/2111778).

**Italic Yellow: Extension functions defined in Kotlin**, whereas normal methods have no color (e.g. `marker.showInfoWindow()` or other methods of this class). Note that this means `String.isBlank()` and `.apply/let/run` are actually implemented as extension methods!